# Autocomplete difficulty in Struts2

Tags: struts2, dojo

I was trying to implement [this autocomplete feature](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-autocompleter-example/). I am getting the drop down for the "What's your lucky number?:" field as it is a hard-coded list.

But I am not getting the drop down for "favorite web framework?". I tried googling other sites like roseindia but did not find a similar problem.

I also noticed that there is no element invoking `action="autoCompleterAction"` in autocompleter.jsp so I tried adding it to `<sx:autocompleter>`, `action="autoCompleterAction"` 
but is was showing error.

Please help me, show me where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)
It is as simple as:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript",
            "Asp"
        ];
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Anshu,Thanks a lot for trying to help but to be frank i totally dont know whats a jquery and my project should be done in struts2 i am using eclipse indigo.With that the above link which i posted i know i have done nearly 70% of autocomplete part but but i need slight corrections to implement the "favourite web framework?" part i am looking for that or any other perfectly working autocomplete example  in struts using values from dynamic list or from databse.